# get focus only by clicking the title bar of xterm

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, xterm, citrix, window-focus

I've suffered this problem many times and so do my colleagues

Sometimes after you stroked some keyboard and mouse combinations this behavior showed up : you have to click a xterm's **title** bar to focus on that term so that you can input, instead of any place in that window.

Whatever you do, minimize, resize don't help. This only thing you can do is logout of that session but all the working history will be gone(of course I can save that but it's awkward)

I'm eagerly wondering is there any solutions to this? I use ctrix XenApp plugin 11.0. The other platform info:

---

Linux 2.6.9-67.ELsmp x86_64

OS:        RedHat Enterprise Linux 4.0 U6

xterm:X.Org 6.8.2(192)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the `reset` command?

Comment: This behavior is controlled in part by the application but mostly by the window manager or desktop environment (something like Gnome, KDE, Fvwm, …; with or without Compiz), and often its configuration. So what is your WM/DE are you using, and what do you know about its configuration?

Comment: @Dennis, no. Acctually, I don't know how to reproduce this issue. I asked to prepare for future:-)

Comment: @Gilles, I choose CDE among the other two, Gnome and IceWM, when I create a new session from Ctrix and this choice window showed up. As for config, no idea... What's that?

Comment: @Dennis, This is an all-terminal-window problem, which means every window need to clicked on title bar to get focused. So you expect 'reset' in every term?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on FocusFollowsMouse.

If you have this on already, look for a keystroke that turns it off and see if that's not the one you're talking about accidentally hitting.